# How to store results of for loop as an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to generate a list of random numbers, before performing a function on them, and storing the original random number and the result as a tuple within an array.

```
# Here is how I'm generating my random integers
celsius = random.sample (range(-10, 40), 35)
print (celsius)

# This is how I store them as an array
array = numpy.array(celsius)
print(celsius)

# This is how I am trying to list my pairs in an array
for n in celsius:
    f = (float(n * 1.8 + 32))
    pairs = (n, f)
    numpy.array(pairs)
    print(pairs)
```

I get a list of pairs but when I print again, it prints the last pair, not the whole list. Additionally the length is listed as two when I check.

Ideally these pairs would be tuples within an array. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how numpy works exactly, but I think you want to append to your numpy array and not just add to that array the way you have it implemented. I think what you are actually doing is just adding the latest value in to that array.

Comment: thanks @idjaw could you show me how to do that?

Comment: I've never used numpy but I believe what you want to do is create your numpy array outside of your loop and then append to it inside your loop. I would assume that numpy array has an append method.

Comment: If you must loop, collect values in a list, and make the array after.  List `append` is good for this.

Comment: @bec check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
import numpy as np

# isolate the wisdom related to the conversion in a function
def celsius2fahrenheit(x):
    return (x * 1.8 + 32)

# generate random values
celsius_arr = np.random.randint(-10, 40, 35)

# compute the converted values
fahrenheit_arr = celsius2fahrenheit(celsius_arr)

# stack them together
pairs_arr = np.stack([celsius_arr, fahrenheit_arr])
```

---

Doing this with an explicit loop would give you suboptimal performances with NumPy arrays, especially if you do not allocate the memory beforehand.

However, just to illustrate how this could be done:

```
import numpy as np

# same as before
def celsius2fahrenheit(x):
    return (x * 1.8 + 32)

# allocate the memory
pair_arr = np.zeros(2, 35)
for i in range(35):
    # generate a random number
    x = np.random.randint(-10, 40)
    # store its value and the converted value
    pair_arr[:, i] = x, celsius2fahrenheit(x)
```

---

Finally, you could use plain Python `list`s, which are more appropriate container for dinamically growing sequences:

```
import random

# same as before
def celsius2fahrenheit(x):
    return (x * 1.8 + 32)

# Option 1: all in a single loop
pairs = []
for _ in range(35):
    x = random.randint(-10, 40)
    pairs.append([x, celsius2fahrenheit(x)])

# Option 2: create two lists to join later
celsius_values = [random.randint(-10, 40) for _ in range(35)]
fahrenheit_values = [celsius2fahrenheit(x) for x in celsius_values]
pair_values = list(zip(celsius_values, fahrenheit_values))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append every 'pairs' result to an empty array/list, this is how I would do it;

```
celsius = random.sample(range(-10, 40), 35)

array = numpy.array(celsius)

final_list = []
for n in celsius:
    f = (float(n * 1.8 + 32))
    pairs = [n, f]
    final_list.append(pairs)

print(final_list)
```

This gives me an output like this - [[0, 32.0], [10, 50.0], [11, 51.8], ... ]]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do is:

```py
#get our list of random celcius numbers
celsius = random.sample (range(-10, 40), 35)
#create an empty list to use later
list = []
#for each element in the list of celcius numbers
for c in celsius:
   #get a farenheit value
   f = float(c*1.8+32)
   #add a sublist consisting of the celsius and fahrenheit numbers to our list
   list += [[c, f]]
#convert the list to a numpy array
array = numpy.array(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not mentioned, the simple list comprehension way:

```
import numpy as np
import random

celsius = np.array(random.sample(range(-10, 40), 35))

def g(i):
    return float(i * 1.8 + 32)

np.array([(i, g(i)) for i in celsius])
```

```
array([[ 27. ,  80.6],
       [ 19. ,  66.2],
       [ 34. ,  93.2],
       [ 39. , 102.2],
       [ 38. , 100.4],
       [  9. ,  48.2],
       [ 25. ,  77. ],
       [ 14. ,  57.2],
       [ 12. ,  53.6],
       [  3. ,  37.4],
       [ -8. ,  17.6],
       [ 16. ,  60.8],
       [ 17. ,  62.6],
       [ 32. ,  89.6],
       [ 35. ,  95. ],
       [  8. ,  46.4],
       [ 33. ,  91.4],
       [ 10. ,  50. ],
       [ 15. ,  59. ],
       [ 18. ,  64.4],
       [ 36. ,  96.8],
       [ 26. ,  78.8],
       [ -6. ,  21.2],
       [ 29. ,  84.2],
       [  5. ,  41. ],
       [ -1. ,  30.2],
       [  6. ,  42.8],
       [ -5. ,  23. ],
       [ 30. ,  86. ],
       [-10. ,  14. ],
       [ -2. ,  28.4],
       [ 31. ,  87.8],
       [ -3. ,  26.6],
       [  7. ,  44.6],
       [  2. ,  35.6]])
```